# Sieve: filter subject with regex, file into mailbox named match

Tags: email-server, dovecot, regex, grep, sieve

I am trying to filter mails by subject with a regular expression.

The subjects I want to match are read like `[git-foo] some more text` where `foo` is the string I want to check for.

I end up with the following

```
require ["fileinto", "variables", "regex"];

if header :regex "subject" "^\[git-.*\]" {
    set :lower :upperfirst "repository" "${1}";

    if string :is "${repository}" "" {
        fileinto "Test/default";
    } else {
        fileinto "Test/${repository}";
    }
}
```

Replacing first `if` statement with `if header :matches "subject" "[git-*" {` files mails into `Test/Foo] some more text` but, when correcting `"[git-*"` to `"[git-*]"`, mails do not match.

Regular expression works with `grep -e`.

What to do to file mail correctly into `Test/Foo`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine both capture groups and double backlashes. Both were mentioned in previous answers, but separately.

```
if header :regex "subject" "^\\[git-(.*)\\]" {
  set :lower :upperfirst "repository" "${1}";
  // ...
}
```

Explanation:

- unlike *:matches*, *:regex* only sets match variables ($1, etc.) for the capture group. *:matches* sets them for each wildcard.
- *:regex* does indeed require escaping `[` and `]`, but with a double backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Does this regex works instead?

'[git-(.*)]'

Comment: Using Thunderbird to set sieve scripts, saving fails: "error: invalid regular expression '[git-(.*)]' for regex match: invalid range end." I also used double quotation marks, otherwise I get way more errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape twice, so that `\[git-.*\]` becomes `\\[git-.*\\]`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late now, but I found that I had to specify folders with dots instead of slashes: eg. 'fileinto "Test.default"'.